# Why accuracy of Neural Network does not change as its structure is changed?

Tags: neural-networks

I have the following neural network:

```
NetIsing = 
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[6], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[5], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[4], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], 
    LinearLayer[3], ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[2], 
    ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], LinearLayer[1], LogisticSigmoid}, 
   "Input" -> {4}];
TrainedIsing = 
 NetTrain[NetIsing, data, BatchSize -> 300, MaxTrainingRounds -> 35, 
  ValidationSet -> data]
```

Where data is a set of 344610 points in the form of `{14, -6.25212, 2.72004, 1} -> {0.0000175528}`.

I am trying to get a better accuracy (to measure accuracy I use `NetMeasurements[TrainedIsing, data, "Accuracy"]`) by changing the number of layers, number of nodes or MaxTrainingrounds.

However, every time that I make any change on the network trying to change its accuracy, I get the exact same value of accuracy (0.911311).

Am I doing anything wrong here?